# featured images are broken while migrating wordpress website from live to local

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, database-migration

I want to migrate a wordpress website from Live to Local Server.
i done the below steps successfully.

1. create database in local phpmyadmin
2. download all the files from live with filezilla.
3. configure the wp-config.php file with my local database details
4. export database from live and imported to local
5. change the siteurl & home in wp_option table
6. run the below sql query.

   ```
   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://www.dfghgfdg.com/fgh/', 'http://localhost/capital/');
   ```

now my website in local running fine with contents and pages. 
but the all featured images are not displaying (broken).

what is the real error. anybody please help me.

Comment: simply use duplicator plugin for that issue

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I migrate a wordpress website, I use the Search & Replace DB (https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB)

You just pop the folder into your plugins folder and write the URL to its index file. A site with various options should be made available for you. All you have to do is provide your old website URL and the new URL for it to replace all instances of it throughout your entire database

Comment: Are the image sources correct? Perhaps you should check your uploads and check if the links are in fact correct.

Comment: Also, you can set your home url in the wp-config.php file like this: define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');